# Concurrent Connections from Browser To IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm running a website that is ASP.NET/JQuery and on IIS 7.0. I've created a web garden with 10  worker threads and a Out of Process (Sql Server) to handle session. I've heard many people suggest that Web Gardens only solve certain problems, being CPU Bottlenecks and the other concurrency.

The Website is one that has dynamic tabbing, and as such attempts to allow the user to multi-task.

Do Web Gardens allow multiple connections from one Browser (Single User)?
That is, if I open two tabs and issue a set of work (with server-side) code, will both requests be submitted or will there only be one connection with blocking, until the first request is completed.

Of course in real life, I am seeing "blocking", when from what I understand Web Garden are too support concurrent connections.

Thanks

Comment: No, HTTP protocol limits to 2 connections per host.

Comment: This is what I've found - when I turn on "web garden" or add multiple worker threads, and I do just that, I get concurrent HTTP requests from client-side. Whether limited to 2 as per the RFC, I don't know; as most browsers have changed that attribute. That being said, when I move then from "In Process" to "SQL Session Management", that breaks it. I've turned off HTTP-Keep Alives, but still limit to one request at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ASP.NET session is your point of contention here - with the in-process session the two browser tabs had separate sessions (which is probably a bad thing) but with the out-of-process session they are trying to access the same one.

From [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the section entitled "Concurrent Requests and Session State":

> if two concurrent requests are made for the same session (by using the same SessionID value), the first request gets exclusive access to the session information. The second request executes only after the first request is finished